# CSS transition on png sequence using jquery not working in Mozilla

Tags: jquery, css

I am creating an animation using a PNG sprite sequence, which will have transition on hover, and animates back when the hover state ends.

http://jsfiddle.net/MLWL5/6/

```js
    $( "div" ).hover(
        function() {
            var elem = $(this);
            var cur = parseInt(elem.css("background-position-x"));
            var steps = (450 + cur) / 50;
            var time = steps * 0.1;
            var trans = "background " + time + "s steps(" + steps + ", end)";
            elem.css("transition", trans);
            elem.css("background-position", "-450px 0px");
        }, 
        function() {
            var elem = $(this);
            var cur = parseInt(elem.css("background-position-x"));
            var steps = - cur / 50;
            var time = steps * 0.1;
            var trans = "background " + time + "s steps(" + steps + ", end)";
            elem.css("transition", trans);
            elem.css("background-position", "0px 0px");
      }
    );
```

```css
div { width:50px; 
    height:72px;             background:url(http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/_images/duke_spritesheet.png) left top;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I have used image sprite and jquery to develop mine and this is working fine on chrome Browser, but does not animate well on Mozilla.

Mozilla is not performing the transition. It is jumping to the final state.

Comment: can you post the code

Comment: please don't try to get around SO rules.  Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code on this site

Comment: You should have a look into the `transition-easing-function: steps;` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function#The_steps()_class_of_timing-functions) as it might simplify your code a whole lot.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't support `background-position-x` as far as I know. Use `background-position` instead and this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `background-position` and `split()` it by space to get the x value of it. and then calculate the rest as you have done in the function.

updated [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/MLWL5/43/)

also, code is

```js
    $( "div" ).hover(
        function() {
            var elem = $(this);
            var cur = parseInt(elem.css("background-position").split(" ")[0]);
            var steps = (450 + cur) / 50;
            var time = steps * 0.1;
            var trans = "background " + time + "s steps(" + steps + ", end)";
            elem.css("transition", trans);
            elem.css("background-position", "-450px 0px");
        }, 
        function() {
            var elem = $(this);
            var cur = parseInt(elem.css("background-position").split(" ")[0]);
            var steps = - cur / 50;
            var time = steps * 0.1;
            var trans = "background " + time + "s steps(" + steps + ", end)";
            elem.css("transition", trans);
            elem.css("background-position", "0px 0px");
      }
    );
```

```css
div { width:50px; 
    height:72px;             background:url(http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/_images/duke_spritesheet.png) left top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Hope this helps